# Any information on magnetic braking with copper?

Tags: magnetics, copper, braking

I have an engineering project where I have to design and build a model of a drop tower from a theme park. The tower itself can be no taller than 40cm.

I plan to use magnetic braking with copper to stop the ride at the bottom. I intend to have the base of the moving seats either made out of magnets or have magnets attached to the side. Then I want to have two copper blocks, maybe 15cm long and 2cm wide/thick, on the inside of the tower itself. The seats would be attached to the front of a block that would move up and down inside the tower. When the seats fall, I would have the copper at the bottom, surrounding the base of the seats and have it slowly descend the last 15cm.

I would appreciate and advice or links on this topic, whether it be how thick the copper needs to be, how strong a magnet would have to be or a link to a paper published on the topic.

I believe this falls under Lenz's law but I'm not certain so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It'll work about the same as with aluminum, just consider the different conductivity of copper in your calculations.

Comment: This is a Physics problem, not an EE problem. Try here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/